# How to filter a multidimentional JSON Object

Tags: arrays, json, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a Json string which contains many json objects, each json has a key, I use JSON.parse to place the string into an object.

I then extract what I need in the following format

```
json['product1'][0].name
```

However, I want to get an array of element from each of the json objects based on the value of another elements. Currently I am using:

```
for each (var row:Object in json) {

    if (row[0][filterElement] == filterValue) {
        arr.push(row[0][element]);
    }

}
```

Is this a good approach? I ask because it seems that I am going through the entire json object every time.

Comment: You can cache search results. Or, maybe pre-cache search results by passing your data once to index all the filter values and relevant arrays. But otherwise you are doing it right, there's no tricks or hidden secrets.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, it sounds like you want to use [`.map`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#map()) and [`.filter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter()).

So if we have an object such as...

```
var obj = {
    people: [
       {name: 'person1'},
       {name: 'person2'},
       {name: 'person3'},
       {name: 'person4'},
    ]
};
```

You can then use `.map` to create a new array of names...

```
var names = obj.people.map(function(person){
     return person.name;
}); // ['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4']
```

on this array you can then use `.filter`...

```
var filter = 'person2';
var filteredNames = obj.people.map(function(person){
         return person.name;
    }).filter(function(name){
        return name == filter; // if true, will push name into a name into our new array
    }); // 'person2'
```

This is obviously a rudimentary example, but the same concepts will apply for the precise properties which apply in your question. Hope this helps.